# Troubleshooting AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Errors with Django Applications - Error: EbExtension build failed

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-deployment

When I was trying to deploy my Django application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Then I got this error.

`2023/12/30 21:26:42.478526 [ERROR] An error occurred during the execution of command [app-deploy] - [PreBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: EbExtension build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.`

What is the reason for that?

Here is my Django.config which is located in .ebextensions folder.

When I remove the 'commands' it gives me 502 bad gateway since the application cannot import the relavant packages.

```
commands:
  01_activate_virtualenv:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate"
  02_install_requirements:
    command: "pip install -r /var/app/current/requirements.txt"

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: django-pixel/core/wsgi.py
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalks keeps many log files for every stages of the deployment. If you got any error from .ebextensions folder, you need to check cfn-init.log. As the error message said:

```
Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
```

You need to ssh into your eb instance and write down: `cat /var/log/cfn-init.log` to view it. For more details look `cfn-init-cmd.log`.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your suggestion. I've successfully used the AWS Elastic Beanstalk tutorial to get my project running with AWS EB CLI. For future reference, I've also published a Django-Elastic Beanstalk starter template on GitHub to help others.

You can find the template here: https://github.com/ranmalmendis/Django-Elastic-Beanstalk-Starter-Template  
                                     
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html